# Filtering the results of a query in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-clause

I'm trying to Query the DB using the following:

```
$products = Product::where('available', true)->get();
```

Then I want to pass the $products to another function to perform more filtering on it.

```
$finalResult = $ProductInstance->searchProducts($products);
```

Knowing that the function searchProducts is written as follows:

```
public function searchProducts($products, $searchValue){
 $finalProducts= $products->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$searchValue}%")->get();
}
```

This is not working as the results returned from the first line of code are stored in a collection. How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: Don't use `->get()` in your first line of code

Comment: This actually worked

Comment: Because `->get()` returns a Collection. Not using it returns a QueryBuilder which you can pass additional QueryBuilder clauses on

Comment: Yeah true. Thank you. If you write it as a post i could set this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$products = Product::where('available', true)->get();` returns a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections), which doesn't support the `LIKE` where feature in `->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$searchValue}%")`.

Change

```
$products = Product::where('available', true)->get();
```

to

```
$products = Product::where('available', true);
```

This will return a [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries) object which you can add additional database queries to and finally return a Collection from your `searchProducts()` method.

Answer (score 1):

`searchProducts($products, $searchValue) {` ... here the **$products** is a **collection** instance not a query builder.

You will have to use [filter()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-filter) with stripos() to mimic `'%' . $searchValue . '%'`

```
public function searchProducts($products, $searchValue){
    return $products->filter(function ($product) use ($searchValue) {
        return false !== stripos($product['name'], $searchValue);
    });
}
```

Keep me posted in the comments below.

Comment: Actually as one pointed out in a comment i only had to delete the get from the first query. But i'm interested in understanding the code you wrote.

Comment: could you please explain this bit return false !== stripos($product['name'], $searchValue);

Comment: @marmahan - `false !== stripos($product['name'], $searchValue);` was the closest thing PHP had to str_contains until the function was introduced in PHP 8.0. The modern equivalent would be `str_contains(strtolower($product['name']), strtolower($searchValue))`. strtolower is required since stripos is case insensitive.